# Any ways to bypass Fortinet blocking web content?

Tags: javascript, proxy, greasemonkey

This may be considered a dupe of my previously asked question but, My ISP uses the software Fortinet to block web content through URL filtering. I'm curious if anyone knows how to bypass this. Fortinet consistently blocks some educational material on accident because the URLs are thrown into a massive pool.

From the Fortinet Wikipedia page: 
"Fortinet is an American multinational corporation headquartered in Sunnyvale, California. It develops and markets cybersecurity software and appliances and services, such as firewalls, anti-virus, intrusion prevention and endpoint security. Fortinet was founded in 2000 by brothers Ken and Michael Xie."
For context.

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to use an extension that can use proxy or other methods to redirect traffic.

It is unreliable to attempt it from a content script (like with GM) which is injected into a tab after HTTP request is made.

Only an extension can get the HTTP request before it is made.

Content script can redirect, if there are any proxifying web-service but that is easy to block.

Comment: thanks for this! I've tried a handful of VPN's and other redirect services, so far the only thing i've gotten to work partially is running the link to the website trough google translate and viewing it in German or other languages. It seems that my ISP has blocked the download an usage of extensions on the issued Chromebooks but, with the computers publicly available i have almost complete control aside form installing exe's and msi's and the web content blocking. I've tried to run a separate OS (Linux Lite) but no dice. @erosman

Comment: @Legacy2988 Most proper proxy extension will work  although those providing free accounts may not be as good. If you have access to a decent HTTPS proxy, I can show you some examples.

Comment: @erosman2 Currently i'm not able to test any at the moment but, i can write them down and try them later.